# Extracting Zip File in Visual Basic .NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, zip

I am working on a Visual Basic Project and i am getting stuck on something super simple. Unzipping a file.

I have the following imports

```
`Imports System.Net
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.Compression`
```

My References are as follows

```
System
System.Core
System.Data
System.Data.DataSetExtensions
System.Deployment
System.Drawing
System.IO.Compression
System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
System.Net.Http
System.Windows.Forms
System.Xml
System.Xml.Linq
```

So what my code should be doing is checking if a software is installed,
if it is not it will download a zip file with the installed.

once the zip is downloaded it should extract it and run the setup.

Everything is working except this code block right here:

```
Private Sub client_OMSADownloadCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show("Download Complete")
    Try
        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory("C:\end.zip", "C:\end")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Can't Extract file" & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

    Public NotInheritable Class ZipFile
    Public Shared Sub ExtractToDirectory(
    sourceArchiveFileName As String,
    destinationDirectoryName As String
)
    End Sub
End Class
```

I get no exceptions, it just doesn't unzip, it basically skips right over the block.

Please help!

Comment: do you receive any error message?

Comment: Nope no error (see edit)
just doesnt run

Comment: Why are you declaring an empty ExtractToDirectory() method?

Comment: Because i put it in wrong, how it is in my code is as such (editing Post)


Public NotInheritable Class ZipFile
    Public Shared Sub ExtractToDirectory(
    sourceArchiveFileName As String,
    destinationDirectoryName As String
)
    End Sub
End Class

Comment: The ExtractToDirectory is not Defined in ZipFile by default as it should be

Comment: Of course it is, look at msdn docs https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485723(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You are executing a method that do nothing

Comment: If i remove the declaration Visual Studio fails out saying it is not declared.

If i view the System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll in Visual studio it does not list it as a method.

Comment: wait.. i am looking again and it is showing it now

Comment: and it is now working once i removed that.

Comment: Thank you so much! i feel quite dumb now xD

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: I've added the answer, if you like accept it as the correct solutions. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According your code, you have inherit the method `ExtractToDirectory` of ZipFile class that do nothing.

```
Public NotInheritable Class ZipFile
    Public Shared Sub ExtractToDirectory(sourceArchiveFileName As String,
                                        destinationDirectoryName As String)
    End Sub
End Class
```

To solve this issue, simple delete this method from your code.

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring `ZipFile` class yourself, while you should use existing one from `System.IO.Compression` namespace. So, just remove following part of your code:

```vb
Public NotInheritable Class ZipFile
    Public Shared Sub ExtractToDirectory(
    sourceArchiveFileName As String,
    destinationDirectoryName As String
)
    End Sub
End Class
```

...and everything should work as expected.